# SQL is trying to execute statements enclosed in an IF block even when the condition is not satisfied

Tags: sql

We upgraded a SQL database, and there have been new columns added to tables in the upgraded version

For example,

`Table1` has columns `Column1, Column2`.

in the upgraded database version, an extra column is added

`Table1` now has columns `Column1, Column2, Column3`

I am trying to create a script that can work in both the versions. This script looks like this:

```
DECLARE @DBVersion varchar(25)

select @DBVersion = (select DBVersion from DBVersions)

IF @DBVersion = 'Old'
  BEGIN
    INSERT Table1 (Column1, Column2)
    SELECT Value1, Value2
    FROM TempTable
  END

IF @DBVersion = 'New'
  BEGIN
    INSERT Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3
    FROM TempTable
  END
```

When I run this script in older database version, I get an error

> Invalid column name 'Column3'

I guess, this is because SQL compiles the script before it executes and is not able to find 
Is there a way I can fix this and develop a script that can run in both the database versions?

Comment: Not sure which RDBMS you're using, but that would be helpful.  Also, are you sure you're doing an equality correctly?  I.e., Some languages use `==` for comparison.  Of course, since I don't know your RDBMS or language, I have no idea.

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** --- SQL is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems - SQL is not a database product... we really need to know what database system (and which version) you're using....

Comment: The statements were not executed. The engine was trying to resolve names in your script and failed, hence the error. (Name resolution happens before the script is executed.) To work around it, use @Thomas's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SQL Server or Sybase, you need to use dynamic SQL for this.

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max);

If @DBVersion = 'Old'
    Set @Sql = 'Insert Table1( Column1, Column2 )
                        Select Value1, Value2
                        From TempTable';
Else If @DBVersion = 'New'
    Set @Sql = 'Insert Table1( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
                        Select Value1, Value2, Value3
                        From TempTable';

exec ( @Sql );
```